# Error: "Could not find build tools necessary to build stringi" when trying devtools::install_github()

Tags: xcode, github, rstudio, devtools

Trying
    devtools::install_github("Rexamine/stringi")
and getting error:
Could not find build tools necessary to build stringi

I see several people have had this error but the solutions haven't worked for me. I reinstalled xcode because the command line tools seemed to be the problem for other people. Checked the paths for R and RStudio, I can open both fine (from the terminal as well). Don't think this is an Rtools issue but I can't figure out where the problem is. Has anyone had any luck with this particular devtools error?

Running OSX 10.11.6, RStudio Version 0.99.896, R 3.2.1 GUI 1.66 Mavericks build (6956), XCode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try running

```
/usr/bin/clang --version
```

If command line tools are installed, this should just report the version of `clang` installed; otherwise, you'll be prompted to install Xcode + Command Line Tools. (This is just a simple way of ensuring command line tools indeed are installed)

If you run

```
devtools::install_github("Rexamine/stringi")
```

in a plain R console, outside of RStudio, what do you see? Can you update your post with the errors (if any) printed to the console?

You might also try updating RStudio to the preview release (https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/) to see if that helps.

---

It seems like this is likely a bug in RStudio's build tools detection; you might try explicitly disabling it with:

```
options(buildtools.check = function(action) TRUE)
```

This should ensure that `devtools` doesn't try to call RStudio's build tools detection code and just assume that everything is available.

Comment: Installs from the R console!

Comment: Must be RStudio, so I updated to the preview release, but still can't install stringi from RStudio

Comment: I first get a message, 'Skipping install of 'stringi' from a github remote, the SHA1 (9c5c9721) has not changed since last install.
  Use `force = TRUE` to force installation'. If I force the install, I get the same error as before