# Quantstrat RStudio R Mac

Tags: r, quantstrat

I am trying to install the package Quantstrat on a Mac.
I searched for help in internet but I did not find a solution.
I already tried:

```
require(devtools)
install_github("braverock/quantstrat")
```

The error message I get is: 
Downloading GitHub repo braverock/quantstrat@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/braverock/quantstrat/zipball/master
Installation failed: Could not find build tools necessary to build quantstrat

Comment: Does it give you any error? If so, which one?

Comment: Downloading GitHub repo braverock/quantstrat@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/braverock/quantstrat/zipball/master
Installation failed: Could not find build tools necessary to build quantstrat

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38725060/error-could-not-find-build-tools-necessary-to-build-stringi-when-trying-devto) could help.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it still does not work. I get a new error this time: ERROR: dependency ‘blotter’ is not available for package ‘quantstrat’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/quantstrat’
Installation failed: Command failed (1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue.

I just needed to open "Xcode" in the Macbook and accept the new terms and conditions. Then I tried again and I was able to download and install Quantstrat.

Comment: Hi, how did you manage to do this? I am having the same issue. Thanks :)

Comment: You need to open Xcode and accept the new terms and conditions. Hope it helps. PF